# Projects sorting Freelancer.com Api

Tags: php, freelancer.com-api

For anyone who worked with Freelancer.com Api.
I trying to fetch all active projects from this platform by API and sort them by recent post date, by default there is sorting by score.
There is nothing said about what sort_field value must be to sort by recent post date.

```
$sorting_date = "????"; 
$requestUrl = "https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/?sort_field=" . $sorting_field;
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestUrl), 1);
```

Here is link to API documentation:
  [Freelancer.com API](https://www.freelancer.com/api/docs/docs.html#projects-projects-get)

Maybe anyone had the same problem?Need help.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/?sort_field=submitdate

Comment: Yes, I tried, but result the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer In short:** 
You can use https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/ without using the `sort_field` because it is also sorted in recent post by default

**Explanation**
I tested the API and I found that this is also **sorted recent posted date** for submitted date

According to Freelancer's Documentation:

> Sorting field, by default searches by score, **otherwise most recently posted**.

I try to limit the result to 3 and reverse it using `reverse_sort` to test if it's actually working.
https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/?limit=3&reverse_sort=true

```
$requestUrl = "https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/?limit=3&reverse_sort=true";
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestUrl), 1);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($response);
```

Here is the [result](https://pastebin.com/NRebtKPT).

Search for `["submitdate"]` by pressing **CRTL + F** and get the value.

Paste the value [here](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators#.WkXHe7eWY1k) to **convert** the **equivalent date**

Here is the **result of reverse_sort** converted date

```
Wed Sep 03 2014 21:14:19 GMT+0800 
Tue Jul 14 2015 23:11:36 GMT+0800
Fri Jul 24 2015 05:46:41 GMT+0800
```

If we **remove the reverse_sort=true** here is the result

```
Fri Dec 29 2017 12:45:13 GMT+0800
Fri Dec 29 2017 12:44:49 GMT+0800
Fri Dec 29 2017 12:44:29 GMT+0800
```

As you can see it is **sort by recent posted date**

Comment: Thanks!Very appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this? This would return projects related to C# ordered by their id.

```
https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active?jobs[]=106&sort_field=id
```